# Wrapper not working?

Tags: html, css, web, wrapper

I am trying to code my portfolio page. And it seems like every time i do a wrapper div. And put everything including the content, footer and sidebar inside the wrapper, that the footer still doesnt seem to always stay at the bottom of the page. When i add more content it goes over the footer. The footer doesnt stay at the bottom. So I need these things fixed if someone can help me.

Here is the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Crescent Moon Designs ~ Coming Soon!</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<!--Begins Wrapper-->
<div id="wrapper">

<!--Begina Header--><div id="header"></div><!--Ends Header-->

<div id="menu_top">

<div id="menu_top1">
<li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Home</a></li>
<li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">About</a></li>
<li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Tutorials</a></li>
<li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Contact</a></li>
</div>

</div>

<!--Starts Sidebar-->
<div id="sidebarleft">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200px"style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="side_title">
Sidebar Title
<img border="0" src="images/sideheader1.png" align="left">
</td>
</tr>
<td id="sidetext">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. 
Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui. 
Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, rutrum dignissim dui. 
</td>
</table>

</div>
<!--Ends Sidebar-->

<!--Starts Content-->
<div id="content_box">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600px" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="content_title">
Content Title
<img border="0" src="images/titleheader1.png" align="left"></td>
</tr>
<td class="content_text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. 
Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui. 
Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, rutrum dignissim dui. 
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
<!--Ends Content-->


<div id="footer">

All Rights Reserved &copy; Crescent Moon Designs 2016


</div>



</div><!--Ends Wrapper-->



</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
body {
    background-image: url('images/mainbg.jpg');
    background-repeat: fixed;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#wrapper {
    margin-left: 240px;
    clear: both;
}

#header {
    background: url('images/cmdblack.png');
    height: 250px;
    width: 800px;
}

#footer {
    margin: auto 0;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: 800px;
}

#sidebarleft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 229px;
    top: 334px;
}

.side_title {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#sidetext {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: verdana, arial, serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #494949;
    padding: 8px;
}

.content_title {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#content_box {
    position: absolute;
    left: 555px;
    top: 334px;
}

.content_text {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: verdana, arial, serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #494949;
    padding: 18px;
}

#menu_top {
    position: absolute;
    left: 273px;
    top: 260px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

#menu_top1 li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-top: 0;
}

li a {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
}

li a:hover {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: italic;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3D3D3D;
    border-radius: 9px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.listimg {
    padding-right: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through and slightly modified your structure. You were using a TABLE tag and tables really should only be used for tabular data, not for layout. I've modified this so it is now using a DIV instead. I've made the following changes to your HTML and CSS -

- I've given the first DIV within your "content_box" the style "width: 600px;".
- I've moved your footer into your "content" area and removed the "position: relative;" as this isn't required.
- I've also removed the "top: 800px" otherwise it will just move it very far from the top of the results. Instead I've now added a "min-height: 800px" on your "content_text" class so that the footer isn't right next to your content when there's only a small amount of content. You can reduce this size if you want to move it up the page.
- You had an error where you and LI tags with no UL parent, I've fixed this too.

Hopefully it achieves what you were seeking. :)

Modified HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Crescent Moon Designs ~ Coming Soon!</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <!--Begins Wrapper-->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!--Begina Header--><div id="header"></div><!--Ends Header-->
        <div id="menu_top">
            <div id="menu_top1">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Home</a></li>
                    <li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">About</a></li>
                    <li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Tutorials</a></li>
                    <li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Starts Sidebar-->
        <div id="sidebarleft">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200px" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="side_title">
                        Sidebar Title
                        <img border="0" src="images/sideheader1.png" align="left">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <td id="sidetext">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu.
                    Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui.
                    Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, rutrum dignissim dui.
                </td>
            </table>

        </div>
        <!--Ends Sidebar-->
        <!--Starts Content-->
        <div id="content_box">
            <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; width: 600px;">
                <div valign="top" class="content_title">
                    Content Title
                    <img border="0" src="images/titleheader1.png" align="left">
                </div>
                <div class="content_text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur vestibulum turpis fermentum ante pharetra aliquam. Duis fringilla sit amet nibh quis ornare. Duis vulputate libero sit amet convallis posuere. Ut iaculis bibendum purus sit amet commodo. Vivamus sit amet posuere nisi. Donec hendrerit congue urna, quis semper nisi ultrices vitae. Proin porta mauris eget turpis sollicitudin, non mattis metus finibus. Sed rhoncus, dolor sit amet interdum posuere, metus neque placerat tellus, nec bibendum elit ante at diam. Aenean eget sodales dolor. Curabitur posuere euismod erat, pharetra venenatis nibh scelerisque eu. Cras rhoncus augue fermentum est interdum egestas. Donec a diam eros.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                All Rights Reserved &copy; Crescent Moon Designs 2016
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Ends Content-->
    </div>
    <!--Ends Wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

Modified CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
body {
    background-image: url('images/mainbg.jpg');
    background-repeat: fixed;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#wrapper {
    margin-left: 240px;
    clear: both;
}

#header {
    background: url('images/cmdblack.png');
    height: 250px;
    width: 800px;
}

#footer {
    margin: auto 0;
    clear: both;
}

#sidebarleft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 229px;
    top: 334px;
}

.side_title {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#sidetext {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: verdana, arial, serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #494949;
    padding: 8px;
}

.content_title {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#content_box {
    position: absolute;
    left: 555px;
    top: 334px;
}

.content_text {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: verdana, arial, serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #494949;
    padding: 18px;
    min-height: 800px;
}

#menu_top {
    position: absolute;
    left: 273px;
    top: 260px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

#menu_top1 li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-top: 0;
}

li a {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
}

li a:hover {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: italic;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3D3D3D;
    border-radius: 9px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.listimg {
    padding-right: 7px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still learning about css and fluid type designs and layouts. It is not as easy at it looks when your beginning at it. But it does take time and practice! :)

Answer (score 0):

Error is inside your HTML code. Please check all the opening tag has their respective closing tags where expected.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 body {
  background-image: url('images/mainbg.jpg');
  background-repeat: fixed;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#wrapper {
  margin-left: 240px;
  clear: both;
}
#header {
  background: url('images/cmdblack.png');
  height: 250px;
  width: 800px;
}
#footer {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: auto 0;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  top: 800px;
}
#sidebarleft {
  position: absolute;
  left: 229px;
  top: 334px;
}
.side_title {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
#sidetext {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: verdana, arial, serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #494949;
  padding: 8px;
}
.content_title {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
#content_box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 555px;
  top: 334px;
}
.content_text {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: verdana, arial, serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #494949;
  padding: 18px;
}
#menu_top {
  position: absolute;
  left: 273px;
  top: 260px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
#menu_top1 li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-top: 0;
}
li a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 10px;
}
li a:hover {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3D3D3D;
  border-radius: 9px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.listimg {
  padding-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<!--Begins Wrapper-->
<div id="wrapper">

  <!--Begina Header-->
  <div id="header"></div>
  <!--Ends Header-->

  <div id="menu_top">

    <div id="menu_top1">
      <li>
        <img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Tutorials</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </div>

  </div>



  <!--Starts Sidebar-->
  <div id="sidebarleft">

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200px" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">

      <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="side_title">
          Sidebar Title
          <img border="0" src="images/sideheader1.png" align="left">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="sidetext">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent
          sed malesuada dui. Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, rutrum dignissim dui.
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </div>
  <!--Ends Sidebar-->

  <!--Starts Content-->
  <div id="content_box">

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600px" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">

      <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="content_title">
          Content Title
          <img border="0" src="images/titleheader1.png" align="left">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="content_text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent
          sed malesuada dui. Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, r Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet
          nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis,
          aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui. Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, r Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor.
          Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum
          tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui. Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, r
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris.
          Praesent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor
          mauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui. Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, r Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet
          quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel
          imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui. Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, r Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
          et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
          et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui. Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum,
          r Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris.
          Praesent sed malesuada dui. Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, rutrum dignissim dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis
          vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui. Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, rutrum dignissim dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui. Nunc nulla libero, ultricies
          eget elit fermentum, rutrum dignissim dui.utrum dignissim dui.
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </div>

  <!--Ends Content-->

  <div id="footer">
    All Rights Reserved &copy; Crescent Moon Designs 2016
  </div>

</div>
<!--Ends Wrapper-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapper should be centered and all of the divs inside should be relative positioned and floating.

You can do something like:

```
#wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 width: 60%; /*you can set the width in px too*/
 left: 50%;
 top: 20px;
 margin: 0 0 0 -30%; /*this will make the div go left half of its width*/
}

#menu_top {
 position: relative;
 width:100%;
 float:left;
 background: #0f0;
}

#footer {
 position: relative;
 width:100%;
 float:left;
 background: #00f;
}
```

And then do the same for all of your other divs. Sidebar can be a div with 20% or 30% and content with 80% or 70%.
This is not the best way of doing it. You should use a framework like Bootstrap.
If you'd like to build your own HTML/CSS then first search by responsive design and grid structures.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following modified code ::

Here is your HTML:

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Crescent Moon Designs ~ Coming Soon!</title>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>

 <body>

 <!--Begins Wrapper-->
 <div id="wrapper">

 <!--Begina Header--><div id="header"></div><!--Ends Header-->

<div id="menu_top">

<div id="menu_top1">
<li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Home</a></li>
<li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">About</a></li>
<li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Tutorials</a></li>
<li><img src="images/moonlisticon.png" class="listimg"><a href="" target="_self">Contact</a></li>
</div>

</div>

<!--Starts Sidebar-->
<div id="sidebarleft">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200px"style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="side_title">
Sidebar Title
<img border="0" src="images/sideheader1.png" align="left">
</td>
</tr>
<td id="sidetext">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse  et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, enenatisvel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu.Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui. Nuncnulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, rutrum dignissim dui. 
</td>
</table>

</div>
<!--Ends Sidebar-->

<!--Starts Content-->
<div id="content_box">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600px"    style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="content_title">
Content Title
<img border="0" src="images/titleheader1.png" align="left"></td>
</tr>
<td class="content_text">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus,venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu.Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui. Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, rutrum dignissim dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis,aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitormauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui. Nunc nulla libero, ultricieseget elit fermentum, rutrum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui. Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, rutrum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et interdum tortor. Nullam eu justo ipsum. Praesent ligula metus, venenatis vel imperdiet quis, aliquet nec lorem. Suspendisse ut elit arcu. Vestibulum eu porttitor mauris. Praesent sed malesuada dui. Nunc nulla libero, ultricies eget elit fermentum, rutrum dignissim dui.
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
<!--Ends Content-->
</div><!--Ends Wrapper-->
<div id="footer">All Rights Reserved &copy; Crescent Moon Designs 2016</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And use the following CSS::

```
@charset "utf-8";
body {
background-image: url('images/mainbg.jpg');
background-repeat: fixed;
background-color: #ffffff;
margin-top: 10px;
}

#wrapper {
float: left;
width: 100%;
}

#header {
background: url('images/cmdblack.png');
}

#footer {
clear: both;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
padding: 20px 0;
}

#sidebarleft {
float: left;
width: 25%;
}

.side_title {
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000000;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#sidetext {
background-color: #fff;
font-family: verdana, arial, serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: #494949;
padding: 18px;
}

.content_title {
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000000;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#content_box {
float: left;
width: 75%;
}

.content_text {
background-color: #fff;
font-family: verdana, arial, serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: #494949;
padding: 18px;
}

#menu_top {
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 20px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#menu_top1 li {
display: inline;
padding: 8px;
padding-top: 0;
}

li a {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: normal;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
padding: 10px;
}

li a:hover {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: italic;
text-decoration: none;
color: #3D3D3D;
border-radius: 9px;
padding: 10px;
}

.listimg {
padding-right: 7px;
}
```

It is the working Code.